Low FPS and lot of delay with my pytorch model
I have a task to process a streaming video from a Hikvision IP camera using OpenCV. Initially, the video’s FPS is around 20-25 with a 2-3 second delay. However, as the code runs for a longer period, the FPS quickly drops and the delay increases. Eventually, the FPS drops to 2-3, and the video freezes.
class VideoLoader:
    @staticmethod
    def load_video(video_path):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter.fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'))
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 25)
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)  
        assert cap.isOpened(), "Video dosyası okunurken hata oluştu"
        return cap

I have tried methods such as using the GPU, employing multithreading, and reducing the resolution, but these haven't been very effective. What do you think is the problem and how can I solve it
def frame_reader(cap, frame_queue):
    while cap.isOpened():
        success, frame = cap.read()
        if not success:
            break
        if not frame_queue.full():  # Check if the queue has space
            frame_queue.put(frame)
    cap.release()
    frame_queue.put(None)  # End-of-stream signal

def video_processor(frame_queue, output_queue, model, class_names, played_sounds):
    threshold = 0.5  # Tespit eşik değeri
    device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
    model.to(device)

    while True:
        frame = frame_queue.get()
        if frame is None:  # End-of-stream signal
            break
        start_time = time.time()
        img = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480))
        img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        img_tensor = torch.from_numpy(img_rgb).permute(2, 0, 1).float().unsqueeze(0).to(device)
        img_tensor /= 255.0  # Normalize

def video_detection(video_source):
    cap = VideoLoader.load_video(video_source)
    model = YOLO("YOLO-Weights/ppe.pt")
    class_names = ['safety-glasses', 'gloves', 'orange-vest', 'yellow-vest',]
    played_sounds = set()

    frame_queue = Queue(maxsize=5)
    output_queue = Queue(maxsize=5)

    reader_thread = threading.Thread(target=frame_reader, args=(cap, frame_queue), daemon=True)
    processor_thread = threading.Thread(target=video_processor, args=(frame_queue,output_queue, model,class_names, played_sounds), daemon=True)

    reader_thread.start()
    processor_thread.start()


Are you sure its the camera could you replicate it with VLC or ffmpeg ? I would suggest you to use pyav, better Error handling and you have more control over the Stream.

@Christoph
Thank you for your advice, but nothing has changed. I'm still experiencing FPS drops and lag.

Did you use now pyav did you see errors, did you measure pkt and FPS to determine whats going on? So it also happen when you just consume the rtsp Stream? What is the longer period?

@Christoph I am currently using PyAV and haven't encountered any errors. However, the FPS continues to drop rapidly after one minute.

then you're looking in the wrong place. the video I/O is not at fault. [mre] required. -- your post has received two upvotes. that is unusual and suspicious. upvotes do not improve your chances. more attention onto a bad question will just get it closed quicker.

@Cemoo it is always one minute ? does it matter wich stream eg main or sub stream ? you should add logging to your code that prints the pts and add a frame calculator and log the fps also. the goal should be that you can be sure its the stream recv or any other issue. did you use rtsp/rtp/tcp or rtsp/rtp/udp ?

also for testing remove your whole threading and yolo stuff.
